# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbp

Tags: android, firebase, google-places-api

i cannot use firebase and places library togheter

I also used the multidex but unfortunately it was not correct

please help me

my gradle:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.atipco.seb"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') {     transitive = false }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:animated-svg-view:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`

And Error :

[Click Here For Show Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eyYN.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472645/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-android-gms-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
```

Check the following:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android